# Getting row values based on array of column names passed to PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up full text search in PostgreSQL 9.2.  I created a new table to hold the content that I want to search (so that I can search across lots of different types of items), which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE search (
    target_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    target_type text,
    fts tsvector
);

CREATE INDEX search_fts ON search USING gin(fts);
```

Every time a new item gets inserted (or updated) into one of the various tables I want to search across, it should automatically be added to the `search` table. Assuming that my table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE item (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, name text NOT NULL, description text);
```

I created a trigger passing in the column names that I want to be able to search:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_item_search BEFORE INSERT
    ON item FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    insert_search('{name, description}'::text[]);
```

Then created a new function `insert_search` as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_search(cols text[]) RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO search (target_id, target_type, fts) VALUES (
      NEW.id, TG_TABLE_NAME, to_tsvector('english', 'foo')
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

My question is, how do I pass in the table values based on `cols` to `to_tsvector`? Right now, the function is getting called and inserts the `id` and `type` correctly, but I don't know the right way to dynamically grab the other values based on the `cols` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to pass arguments, just send them directly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_item_search BEFORE INSERT
    ON item FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    insert_search('name', 'description');
```

And, from PL/pgSQL you will get those arguments as an array, called `TG_ARGV`. But, the problem is that PL/pgSQL cannot get the values from `NEW` record based on their names. To do that you can either use a language that lets you do that (like PL/python or PL/perl) or use the [`hstore` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html).

I'd stick with the last one and use `hstore` (unless you already use one of the other languages to create functions):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_search() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
        v_new hstore;
BEGIN
        v_new = hstore(NEW); -- convert the record to hstore
        FOR i IN 0..(TG_NARGS-1) LOOP
                INSERT INTO search (target_id, target_type, fts) VALUES (
                  NEW.id, TG_TABLE_NAME, to_tsvector('english', v_new -> TG_ARGV[i])
                );
        END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

As you can see above, I used the `hstore`'s operator `->` to get the value based on the name (on `TG_ARGV[i]`).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating the tsvector first and then inserting into the search table (since INSERT in the loop breaks primary key constraint) but this got me most of the way there.

Comment: @Bill, as you were passing two arguments, I thought you needed to insert multiple registers... But you can adapt as you wish, I'm glad it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameters specified in the trigger definition with the `TG_ARGV` variable.  You can find documentation on that [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).  `TG_ARGV` is an array accessed by a 0 based index.  So it would be something like `TG_ARGV[0]`, `TG_ARGV[1]`, and so on.